# installing ubuntuGNOME 16.04 on Thinkpad T440?

Tags: 14.04, thinkpad

I recently got hands on a Thinkpad T440 core i7 4600U 2.7ghz 8gb RAM 180ssd, I want to install Ubuntu gnome as main OS, any idea if it will work? At the moment I have a VM (VirtualBox) on it with ubuntu 14.04 but the GUI is very slow. I wondered if by installing it as OS it will perform better. any advice??

Comment: Try a live session and check whether all the hardware is correctly recognized and working (don't worry about WiFi as some require additional drivers/firmware and may not work out of the box). A normal installation uses all the real hardware whereas in a VM the OS accesses and uses the virtualized hardware only.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 17.04 on a T440p right now. Everything works as expected. I ran 16.04 earlier with the same result.

Comment: For your VB slowness, configure the guest with 2 CPU's and 2048 memory, and it should fly.

Comment: I ran Ubuntu (I think it was 14.04) on a T440 and it was buttery smooth and slick (even though I was using "spinning rust" at the time). I currently have a T450 running Kubuntu 17.10, and it's buttery smooth and slick. The "T" line of ThinkPads are usually very Linux friendly. Most things "just work" out of the box (I say "most things" because I've never tried to get the fingerprint reader working - just not interested in it). The one thing I hated about the T440 was the touchpad - Lenovo should have been sued for that monstrosity! I swapped mine out for a T450 mouse.

Comment: Also, if by "installing as an OS" you mean installing to the drive (i.e. not in a VM), then I would say "Yes! Definitely do it!!". As mentioned in my comment above, ThinkPads love Linux (at least the T-series do). For me, personally, it has been a very smooth and hassle free experience. My T450 is my travel companion, and it "just works" whenever I have to hook it up to a projector :). Dual boot it with Windows if you have to keep Windows. I used to dual-boot, but now I find Windows to be a waste of space.

Comment: @VanessaDeagan i replaced my trackpad with the three button trackpad from a T450.

Comment: @AlejandroNova - I think the one thing I had to do manually was create an /etc/X11/xorg.conf file and set the acceleration method to UXA (or SNA, can't remember which now). This may have been fixed in later versions of Ubuntu. So create a `Section "Device"` and then within that section: `Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"`. Oh, I think I also had `Option       "TearFree" "true"` in that section. This may or may not be needed any more. If you experience any kind of tearing, throw it in there.

Comment: Im happy to share that i tried and it worked the proceeded with install. Thanks everyone for the input.

Answer (score 1):

> any advice??

Yes: Just try it, but make sure you use a recent distribution and kernel (>= 4.10, as with that version the support for mobile processors and power management has greatly improved). For Thinkpads the chances are usually good that most hardware works out of the box, and you can find support for the rest.

Comment: The T440 has the 4th gen Intel CPU, which will work just fine with older kernels. I was getting around 4 hours battery life on the "3 point something" kernel (cannot remember exactly which one it was now). However, I take your point that there may be power management improvements in later kernels. One way to find out is to install and run "powerstat". From memory, I think mine was using around 5watts at idle (again, it was a while ago now, so I could be wrong).